# How can I separate Firebase event analytics by platform?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-analytics, sdk

We have an iOS app, an Android app and a Web app, all utilizing Firebase for analytics. In Firebase, these are listed under the Prod 'project' as different apps within the same project.

I noticed for our list of events, it seems our apps are sharing similar events. Such as when a user logs in, etc.

But how can I dig into those event analytics and see what platform each event was triggered from? How can I check how login events come from Web alone?

Obviously I could make a custom event called 'Web Login Event' but that seems like it would go against our Event naming standards and possibly clutter our list of Events. Any way to separate event analytics by platform (app) out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase, despite having a robust data structure, provides extremely poor toolset to access the data and query it properly.

You want to [connect your Firebase to GA4](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9289234?hl=en). Once done, you will have all your data in a proper space for analysis since GA4's data structure was completely copied from that of Firebase. Since GA4 is still a new and certainly buggy product, it is advised to only use the explorer and change the data retention setting to the maximum that's allowed to you. By default, it's just 2 months.

Now that should solve your analysis requirements, but if you need to go even deeper than that, you can always [link your GA4 property to BQ](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9823238?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) and then have the full power of SQL at your feet.